# Template deduction of Base method called by Derived object

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, templates, metaprogramming

I'm trying to deduct a template of a function based on the class of the object invoking the function. How can I do this?

```
#include <type_traits>
struct B;

template<typename T>
bool f(const T*) { return std::is_same<T, B>::value; }

struct A {
    bool g() { return f(this); }
};
struct B:A {};

int main() {
        B b_obj;
        return b_obj.g(); // returns false
}
```

Making `g` virtual doesn't help either.
How can I make `b_obj.g()` return true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the below ways require modification of the code:

#### Runtime polymorphism (preferred IMO)

Make the callable function a non-template `virtual` method of base class. i.e.

```
struct A {
  virtual bool f () { /* code */ }
  bool g() { return f(); } // no argument to be passed now!
};    
struct B : A { bool f () override { /* code */ } };
```

#### Static polymorphism (using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern))

```
template<class Child>
struct A {
  bool g() { return f(static_cast<Child*>(this); }
};
struct B : A<B> {};
```

Comment: First one is what I wanted to avoid (implementing method in all subclasses). Second is perfect! Thank you!